# Unable to get the value of child in firebase other than null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Not sure why, but with the code I have, I cannot seem to get the value of 'isOnline':

```
dolRef = DatabaseReference dolRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversOnline");
dolRef = dolRef.child("iosDriver");
dolRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String driverid = ds.getKey();

            // get value of 'isOnline'
            dolRef = dolRef.child(driverid);
            Log.e(TAG, "dolRef: " + dolRef);
            dolRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot dss : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String online = dss.child("isOnline").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.e(TAG, "Online: " + online);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Below is a part of my firebase db:

```js
"DriversOnline" : {
    "iosDriver" : {
      "BruEGfToc8axIWJk1o01fxcwd8I2" : { // driverId
        "isOnline" : "true",
        "latitude" : 45.276,
        "longitude" : -66.064
      }
    }
  }
```

Any idea why I can't get the value of 'isOnline' other than null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're nesting your listeners one level deeper than needed.

```
DatabaseReference iosRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversOnline/iosDriver");
iosRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot driverSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String driverid = driverSnapshot.getKey();

            DataSnapshot isOnlineSnapshot = driverSnapshot.child("isOnline");

            System.out.println(isOnlineSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Some things to note:

- Reassigning one generically named `dolRef` variable 4 times in a block of code like this is a code-smell. It makes it much harder to follow what's going on, and to check if the variable points to the right location. Give each of them a name that clearly indicates what they point to, as I've done above.
- There is no need to attach a second listener, as the value of `isOnline` is right in the `driverSnapshot`. You can just request the child snapshot with the right name, and then the value from that.
- Don't ignore error, as that hides potential problems. At the very least throw them, as I've done above.

Comment: The thing is don't we have to include for each driverId? and isOnlineSnapshot, is that a String?

Comment: What type is isOnlineSnapshot?

Comment: It's a `DataSnapshot`. I added that, although keep in mind: your IDE should also give a clear indication of the type returned by `DataSnapshot.child()`, as does the reference documentation for that method: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot.html#child(java.lang.String)

Comment: Ok, I will give it a try, can you take a look at another post of mine?  I was hoping to see you at some point!

Comment: You're already looping over each driver with `for(DataSnapshot driverSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())`, so there's no need use an additional listener. The only time you'll need that is if the data is in another part of the JSON.

Comment: when I put what you have above, the isOnlineSnapshot inside print stmt is RED.

Comment: that works!  great, I will keep that to refer back to til I know automatically!  Thanks, and oh that other post, I know YOU can solve, please:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54174272/when-sending-data-from-app-to-firebase-functions-to-paypal-notification-email-i

Comment: Hi @LizG. If this answer is correct, please consider accepting it. It is not mandatory to do so on Stack Overflow, but doing so will encourage helpers to help more, as well as being a helpful solution indicator for future readers. If you are not familiar with answer acceptance, let me know, and I will find a link for you that explains it.

Answer (score 0):

```
driverid = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("driver");//If there is another driver table, the path must be two layers.
driverid.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
             @Override
             public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                  Driver driver = dataSnapshot.getValue(Driver.class);//class model

                 dolRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversOnline/iosDriver").child(driver.getDriverID);
                 dolRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            DriversOnline driversOnline= dataSnapshot.getValue(DriversOnline .class);//class model
                        log.d("driverid","isOnline :"+driversOnline.getisOnline)
                        //display -> isOnline : true


            }

                  @Override
                   public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                 }
        });

}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});
```